How can I measure the memory and cpu used by a specific request in ASP.NET Core Web API?
I want to see which API calls use more memory and cpu.
I tried to create middleware that tracks memory and cpu usage and they can't track only current request's metrics. I want to see which API calls takes how much CPU and memory in production

In short - you can't. In theory you can measure the memory but that will affect the CPU consumption. I would argue that more interesting question is why exactly you want to do that.

Why you want to do that , are you trying to optimize memory usage and CPU consumption? Usually we monitor the whole system instead of each single request as it is more feasible and meaningful.

It is probably too complicated to check this in production due to fact that one async operation can be executed in multiple threads. But comparative CPU and memory consumption should be the same in dev environment. So, if you want, you can run performance tests in an isolated dev environment. I think in production for specific request performance we can use only time based metrics.
